# This VBA Macro Is Destroying My File and Dont Know Why

Tags: vba, excel, userform

so last night everything was working fine and now this is happening. not sure where the issue is, all other macros work fine and I've narrowed it down to one userform which is causing all the errors. its a Warehouse Managment File I'm working on, and the add a new entry feature (add new line form) is freezing the whole file.

[image: main sheet img]

[image: add line img]

```
 Sub addline()
' Adds line to top row, currently row 12

   If UserForm2.TextBox3.Text = "" Then
   UserForm2.TextBox3.Text = "Today"
   End If
   UserForm2.Show
    'form2  does the rest of the code, this part works fine
End Sub
```

code for userform2:

```
Dim strdate As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   If Not TextBox1.Text = "" Then
       If Not TextBox2.Text = "" Then
           If Not TextBox3.Text = "" Then

               Sheets("Main").Rows(12).Select
               Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
               Range("B12").Value = False
               Range("C12").Value = TextBox1.Text
               Range("D12").Value = TextBox2.Text
               'makeing the vlookup
               Range("E12").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],rhconv,5,False),""#ERROR"")"
               'adding the date tag
               Range("f12").NumberFormat = "@"
               If TextBox3.Text = "Today" Then
                   strdate = Format(Now(), "mmm dd , yyyy")
                   Range("F12").Value = strdate
               Else  ' else just add the date provided
                   Range("F12").Value = TextBox3.Text
               End If

            UserForm2.Hide
            Range("e12").Select
            If Selection.Value = "#ERROR" Then

                ' this is for the vlookup, if theres no match let the user know

                MsgBox "Line Match Not Found. Please add a match into the system or delete 
                the line and start again."
               Else
                   TextBox1.Text = ""
                   TextBox2.Text = ""
                   TextBox3.Text = "Today"
               End If

               'not sure why but theres a mistake somewhere posting C12 to A12 and G12 when this code works :P
               Range("a12").Value = ""
               Range("g12").Value = ""

           Else
               ' if not everything filled dont let the user move on

               MsgBox "Please fill in all fields before Sumbitting, or Cancel"
           End If
       Else
           MsgBox "Please fill in all fields before Sumbitting, or Cancel"
       End If
   Else
       MsgBox "Please fill in all fields before Sumbitting, or Cancel"
   End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
      ' cancel button, works fine i thing the error is in the submit button above
    UserForm2.Hide
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
End Sub
```

I know its alot of code but its driving me nuts, also im a bit of a novice so ill need a bit of help. thanx

Comment: put breakpoints on the lines that could be causing the issue.

Comment: Do you know how to [debug code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wooow! i found the issue, I kept getting "not enough ram" issues from this code just to find the issue was in the inserting of the row.

from this

```
Sheets("Main").Rows(12).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

to this

```
 Sheets("Main").Range("B12").Entirerow.Insert
```

wonder why the debugger never caught this?
didnt know the "Entire Row" ment soo much